# Atributo href exclusivamente para baliza <a></a>?

Tags: html, html5, html-tags

É correto colocar o atributo `href` numa outra baliza que não seja `a`.

Exemplo:

```html
<ul>
  <li href="#page1">Page1</li>
  <li href="#page2">Page2</li>
  <li href="#page3">Page3</li>
  <li href="http://www.google.fr">Page3</li>
</ul>
```

Aparentemente funcionou no meu caso, mas isso é correto?

Comment: O que você chama de "funcionou"? Aqui simplesmente é ignorado. Pode ser que seu browser faça algo fora do padrão e use o href para alguma coisa, mas é "invenção" do fabricante. .

Comment: No exemplo da do meu post claramente nao funciona, mas integrando no meu app esta a funcionar colocar. Que problemas poderei encontrar futuramente ?

Comment: O problema você já encontrou, que é "funcionar". Não é pra funcionar, se "funciona" tem algo errado com o APP agora mesmo, e não futuramente. Quando algo funciona quando não devia, é sinal de coisa errada também.

Comment: kkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk Pega leve mano !!!

Comment: É sério, não tou "zoando" não, seria absurdo você contar com algo que não devia ser assim, pois o resultado é imprevisível. Pode ser uma coincidência e funcionar só em raros casos. Pode ser um JS que tá usando os links, e não a webview ou navegador. Não dá pra confiar nadinha nisso.

Comment: A exceção para isso seria você encontrar na documentação oficial da plataforma algo assim: "Foi estendido o suporte ao href em todos os elementos ..." etc, assim seria algo oficial. De resto, é melhor não arriscar.

Comment: Entendo perfeitamente as suas tendências de precaução, e valeu !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

É incorreto em `li`. Já dá para perceber que não funciona no exemplo da pergunta. Esse atributo é especificado como pertencente a algumas *tags*, como `<a>`, `<area>`, `<base>` e `<link>`. Então quando o uso em outro local ele é considerado um atributo personalizado e provavelmente será desconsiderado.

[Documentação MDN sobre atributos](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes).

[Documentação na W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html).

Comment: No exemplo da do meu post claramente nao funciona, mas integrando no meu app esta a funcionar colocar. Que problemas poderei encontrar futuramente ?

Comment: É possível que o renderizador que está usando aceite isto, mas não é oficial e não deve ser usado. A pergunta não tem detalhes sobre esse renderizador. Se tiver algo que diga oficialmente que pode usar, então pode se quiser que só funcione nele. Funcionar é diferente de estar certo. As coisas funcionam por coincidência, e isto não basta se quer fazer o certo.

Answer (score 1):

Creio ser incorreto:

Segundo [W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-li-element) :

> > 4.4.7 The li element
> >     Content attributes:
> >     Global attributes

Conteúdo atributos:[**Global**](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#global-attributes)  atributos e `href`, não é um atributo global.